# what does QueryDirectory operation in procmon means

Tags: procmon

On tracking a process with procmon. I see several operation types. I am unable to find 
any detailed explanation for them. There is one called **QueryDirectory** 
what does it mean.

Comment: I don't know more simple answer than this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntquerydirectoryfile